# Cannot Get Accordion to Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5 Accordions. They work but I wanted to add smooth transitions. I did that, then it threw a TypeError. Once this issue was resolved no errors are thrown but the script doesn't close the open panels!

How do I get the panels to close?

Here is the script used:

```
$(function() {
 $(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function (event) {
   $("dd.active").find(".content").slideToggle("slow");
   $(this).find(".content").slideToggle("slow");

   var current =  $(event.currentTarget);
   if (current.hasClass('active')) {
      current.removeClass('active');
   } 
 })
});
```

I thought that this would take care of the open panels:

```
var current =  $(event.currentTarget);
   if (current.hasClass('active')) {
      current.removeClass('active');
   }
```

But it works the first time then doesn't after this.

How do I solve this problem?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcUpn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to close a panel, `slideUp()` method should be used, you can also use `:not()` selector for excluding the active element:

```
$(".accordion").on("click", "dd:not(.active)", function (event) {
   $("dd.active").removeClass('active').find(".content").slideUp("fast");
   $(this).addClass('active').find(".content").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J8456/